# Python Classes - Beginner

Tags: python, class

I'm a new python student and I'm really having some hard time with classes. So I have to make a class named Positions, with constructor, selectors and so on.
The constructor is supposed to receive 2 ints and return the position made by the 2 ints, so if I receive the numbers 2,3 it will return the position (2,3).
Its the first time I'm making a class after reading online.

What's wrong with this?

```
class Position:    
    def __init__(self,column,line):
        self.c = column
        self.l = line

    def position(self):
        return (self.c,self.l)
```

and the other one where they give me a position and I have to return only the line. so if they give me (2,3) it should return 3.

```
 def position_line(self):
    return self.l
```

Please give me some tips :)

Comment: So what's your problem then? Did you try this out, what errors did you get, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I tested it out..it just return execution errors after I run the tests..I was wondering what was wrong there?

Comment: wha system executes these tests? It sounds like an online learning platform like udacity or codecademy (not sure if codecademy teaches python)

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine. The only thing you may want to do is ad an underscore before your instance variables. This is a convention in python to show that these variables are private, I'll go into a bit more detail on that later.

```
class Position:    
    def __init__(self,column,line):
        self._c = column
        self._l = line

    def position(self):
        return (self._c,self._l)
```

This shows to other people reading your code, that these variables are private, and should not be accessed from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. You could just do it like this:

```
    p = Position(2, 3)
    p.position_line()
```

And this will print 3.
Hope this will help.